# Подписка пользователей на обновления

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Не получается дополнить запрос mysql.

Имеются две таблицы: books, read

```
books - все книги, которые добавляют пользователи {
id - Идентификатор.
id_sender - Id отправителя книги.
name - Название.
time - время добавления.
}

read - кто на какую книгу подписан{

kto - id пользователя, который читает
kogo - id пользователя, за которым следит пользователь

}
```

P.S. Изменил таблицу для удобства.

Запрос мой:

```
SELECT c.* FROM books c, read s '. 'WHERE c.id_sender = s.kogo AND s.kto = '.$id.' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kto - id пользователя, который читает // а что он читает какую книгу? где ID книги
kogo - id пользователя, за которым следит пользователь
```

А где id книги которую читают?

Совет. изначально правильно составить структуру БД и таблиц в ней.

Пока, если честно, вопрос звучит **так** а внутренности звучат **иначе**.

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: Возможно, да. Все же можно книгу назвать простым сообщением, которое отправляет пользователь, а пользователь подписывается на нужного пользователя и все его сообщения отображаются на одной странице. Принцип твиттера - следить за кем хочешь. Если можете написать запрос со своими выдуманными таблицами, то буду благодарен, разберусь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> > Суть проблемы: показывать так же свои обновления, как будто я подписан на себя.

```
... s.who = s.whom AND s.whom = '.$id.' ...
```

?

Comment: йоу, а я и не заметил такого :) вот жешь блин...

Comment: c.id_sender = s.whom AND s.whome = '.$id.' - выводятся только мои обновления.

c.id_sender = s.whom AND s.who = '.$id.' - выводятся только чужие обновления на кого подписан.

Comment: c.id_sender = s.whome AND s.who = '.$id.' AND s.whom = '.$id.' - Ничего не выводится вообще.